# Sql insert query slow down while inserting 100k records

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I have table which contain 20 million records.
daily I delete 100K records and 100K record are inserted but when i inserting records it takes more time.

table has one clustered index (primary key).

I already tried sp_updatestats after deleting records

Comment: I recommend you first read a few hints about **[how to ask perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)** and **[how to create create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then edit your question accordingly to attract more people to your post.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. @MarcinOrlowski has a good suggestion. Also please read this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ and pay special attention to the section on query performance. Then [edit] your question.

Comment: "More time" means nothing for us. Firstly, "more" must be comparing to something, and even it was "a lot of time", it could still be 10 minutes or 10 hours.

Answer (score 0):

So, you are keeping about 200 days's worth of data?  (Perhaps 6 months?)  And you are deleting the oldest day?  What is the `PRIMARY KEY`?  Perhaps an `AUTO_INCREMENT`?  If not, then we need to study it.  And you have some datetime or timestamp column.

`PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(datetime))` into about 28 weeks.  Then `DROP PARTITION` weekly and `REORGANIZE PARTITIONS future INTO next_week, future`.  More details [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) .

With that, the delete will be 'instantaneous', as will the creation of a new partition.  And the other partitions will not be messed with, thereby avoiding whatever is currently causing it to "take more time".

If you need to discuss this further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and tell us how you were doing the big delete.

Answer (score 0):

You're experiencing table bloat. Disk space is never freed up by mysql when you delete records so selects and inserts need to seek past all the garbage you've deleted causing your slow downs. This is one of the main reasons why I choose to use postgres for non-trivial projects. Your actual problem is your database setup choices.

Your best bet is partitioning your tables by date. I've found this speeds things up greatly in your situation. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-range.html

EDIT: this might be worth your time to read as well: https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/reclaim-your-hard-drive-saving